# Passing my home route a default value in VueJS

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

My router currently looks like:

```
export default new Router({
    mode: 'history',
    base: process.env.BASE_URL,
    routes: [
        {
            path: '',
            name: 'home',
            component: Home
        },
        {
            path: '/:set',
            name: 'set',
            component: Set
        },
    ]
})
```

I would like this to actually look something like:

```
export default new Router({
    mode: 'history',
    base: process.env.BASE_URL,
    routes: [
        {
            path: '',
            name: 'home',
            component: Set,
            set: 'set-value-here'
        },
        {
            path: '/:set',
            name: 'set',
            component: Set
        },
    ]
})
```

The change is that the URL path is still '', but I want it to load the component **Set** with the set variable being coded in.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try meta fields?

```js
export default new Router({
    mode: 'history',
    base: process.env.BASE_URL,
    routes: [
        {
            path: '',
            name: 'home',
            component: Set,
            meta: {
              set: "set-value-here"
            }
        },
        {
            path: '/:set',
            name: 'set',
            component: Set
        },
    ]
})
```

You can access it when the component rendered

```js
mounted() {
  console.log(this.$route.meta.set);
},
```

You can pass default values using meta fields.

[Route Meta Fields](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/meta.html)

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible as I know it. But you can do something else. You can pass your parameter to your Home Component and then based on value of your parameter, you can call for different components.

Edit 1:

Something like this I guess:

```
export default new Router({
    mode: 'history',
    base: process.env.BASE_URL,
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/:set?',
            name: 'home',
            component: Home
        },
    ]
})
```

And in your Home component you can use this:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div v-if="set === null">
            // Continue Home Component
        </div>
        <div v-else>
            <set-component></set-component>
        </div
    </div>
</template>

and etc...
```